# ANDROID - RadioButton Switch or IF how to use?

Tags: java, android

Good day.
I am new to Java and Android.
I'm trying to make a simple application, even for focused learning, but I have some doubts.
I intend to make an application as follows:
Two RadioButton within a RadioGroup;
Three EditText;
One Button.

The User would select the RadioButton you want, soon after would inform a cash value (Example: $ 1,000.00, $ 5,000.00 ...);
After informing the time (Example: 3 months, 5 months, 12 months ...);
Finally inform the interest in "%" that want to charge. (Example: 2, 5, 10 ...).

When User click the button to make the calculation should see a message on your screen telling the full amount.

My doubt is:
I'm having trouble getting the information about the RadioButton, I can not make it go into the desired option by the User.
Already utilized IF and now I'm trying SWITCH.
Please, if anyone knows what I'm doing wrong and tell me I thank you very much, remembering that I'm starting now in Java and also on Android. Sorry for my English because I speak another language, I hope you understand me. Thank you!

---

Java code

package com.example.cleberspirlandeli.calculajuros;

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;

public class CalculaJuros extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private RadioButton rdbDias;
    private RadioButton rdbMeses;
    private Button btnCalcular;
    private EditText txtTempo;
    private EditText txtJuros;
    private EditText txtValor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calcula_juros);

        rdbDias = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rdbDias);
        rdbMeses = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rdbMeses);
        btnCalcular = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalcular);
        txtTempo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtTempo);
        txtJuros = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtJuros);
        txtValor = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtValor);

        btnCalcular.setOnClickListener(this);
    } //FIM Protected Void

        public void onClick(View v) {

            double resultado1 = 0;
            double resultado2 = 0;

            String v1 = txtTempo.getText().toString();
            String v2 = txtJuros.getText().toString();
            String v3 = txtValor.getText().toString();

            if (v1.trim().isEmpty() || v2.trim().isEmpty() || v3.trim().isEmpty()) {
                AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                dlg.setMessage("Ha Campos Em Branco");
                dlg.setNeutralButton("Ok", null);
                dlg.show();

            } else {

            //    switch (R.id) {
            //        case R.id.rdbDias:
                        if (rdbDias.isSelected() == true) {
                            double valorTempo = Double.parseDouble(txtTempo.getText().toString());
                            double valorJuros = Double.parseDouble(txtJuros.getText().toString());
                            double valorValor = Double.parseDouble(txtValor.getText().toString());

                                for (int i = 0; i < valorTempo; i++) {
                                    resultado1 = (valorValor * valorJuros) / 100;
                                    resultado2 = valorValor + resultado1;
                                } // FIM FOR

                            AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                            dlg.setMessage("RadioButton1 - Valor Total : R$" + resultado2);
                            dlg.setNeutralButton("Ok", null);
                            dlg.show();

                        } // END IF
            //            break;

            //        case R.id.rdbMeses:
                      else if (rdbMeses.isSelected() == true) {
                            double valorTempo2 = Double.parseDouble(txtTempo.getText().toString());
                            double valorJuros2 = Double.parseDouble(txtJuros.getText().toString());
                            double valorValor2 = Double.parseDouble(txtValor.getText().toString());

                                for (int i = 0; i < valorTempo2; i++) {
                                    resultado1 = (valorValor2 * valorJuros2) / 100;
                                    resultado2 = valorValor2 + resultado1;
                                } // FIM FOR

                            AlertDialog.Builder dlg2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                            dlg2.setMessage("RadioButton2 - Valor Total : R$" + resultado2);
                            dlg2.setNeutralButton("Ok", null);
                            dlg2.show();

                        } // END IF


              //          break;
        //        }
            }
        }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_calcula_juros, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
} // END PUBLIC CLASS






------------------------------------------------------------------------
.xml Code

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".CalculaJuros"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Bem Vindo"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="DIAS"
            android:id="@+id/rdbDias"
            android:checked="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="MESES"
            android:id="@+id/rdbMeses"
            android:checked="false" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Valor R$"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/txtValor" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Tempo"
        android:id="@+id/textView3" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/txtTempo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Juros ( % )"
        android:id="@+id/textView4" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/txtJuros" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calcular"
        android:id="@+id/btnCalcular"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try using isChecked() instead of isSelected()

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to check if the isSelected method is equal to true.  Try changing your if statements like the following example:

```
if (rdbDias.isSelected()) {
     //do something
}
else {
     //do something else
}
```

If you have more than two radio buttons, you can use the format if, else if, else if, else, etc.

You can also use the switch format for radio buttons. If you would rather use switch format for checking your radio buttons, here is an example from the Android developer documentation:

```
    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_pirates:
            if (checked)
                // Pirates are the best
            break;
        case R.id.radio_ninjas:
            if (checked)
                // Ninjas rule
            break;
    }
}
```

You can see more detail in the Android developer documentation on radio buttons here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html